# how to access Google Scholar using Perl

Tags: perl, cgi, www-mechanize, lwp

I'm using the code below to try to search Google Scholar from my website and it will work once or twice and then I get the error "Error GETing http://scholar.google.com: Can't connect to scholar.google.com:80 (Permission denied)" - the code I'm using is as follows:

```
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $browser = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$browser->get('http://scholar.google.com');
$browser->form_name('f');
$browser->field('q','PCR');
$browser->submit();
print $browser->content();
```

Any tips or advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you need to use `https://scholar.google.com`?

Comment: http://scholar.google.com redirects me to the https url.

Comment: Yes, it is the correct URL, and as I mentioned it works occassionally as http and not https secure

Comment: Your code works fine for me here. Which implies that you issue is probably down to your local network configuration. Do you need to do something with proxy settings?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is just fine, but Google Scholar decided not to allow access by "bots" like LWP, see [perlmonks/461130](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=461130) for more information.

Edit: I found a solution by passing user-agent and a cookie id in the header:

```
use HTTP::Request;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use LWP::UserAgent;

# randomize cookie id
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);
my $googleid = md5_hex(rand());

# escape query string
use URI::Escape;
my $query= uri_escape('search string');

# create request
my $request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q='.$query);

# disguise as Mozilla
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent('Mozilla/5.0');

# use random id for Cookie
my $cookies = HTTP::Cookies->new();
$cookies->set_cookie(0,'GSP', 'ID='.$googleid,'/','scholar.google.com');
$ua->cookie_jar($cookies);

# submit request
$response = $ua->request($request);
if($response->is_success){
    print $response->code;
    my $text = $response->decoded_content;
    # do something
}
```